# How do I create a view in SQL Server 2014 to see data from cross referenced tables where some data is missing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to generate a report from a normalized database with tables a, a_xref_b, and b.

```
CREATE TABLE a (a_rid INT primary key, a1 varchar(20), );

CREATE TABLE b (b_rid INT primary key, b1 varchar(20), b2 varchar(20));

CREATE TABLE a_xref_b (a_rid INT, b_rid INT,xref_type int
CONSTRAINT fk_a FOREIGN KEY (a_rid) REFERENCES a (a_rid),
CONSTRAINT fk_b FOREIGN KEY (b_rid) REFERENCES b (b_rid));

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,'John'), (2,'Sue')
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1,'Atlanta','GA'), (2,'Macon','GA'), (3,'Opp','AL')
INSERT INTO a_xref_b VALUES (1,1,1), (1,2,2), (2,3,1)
```

Table A and B are cross-referenced and have the cross reference has a type, which defines what the data in B represents.

Scenario - John is provided a main city and an alternate.  Sue only provided a main city.

I am trying to write a view to load page that has the name, main city, and alternate.

```
Name   b_rid_t1  City_t1   St_1  b_rid_2   City_t2  St_t2
John   1         Atlanta   GA    2         Macon    GA
Sue    3         Opp       AL    NULL      NULL     NULL
```

I tried this

```
select
   a.a1,
   b_1.b_rid,
   b_1.b1,
   b_1.b2,
   b_2.b_rid,
   b_2.b1,
   b_2.b2      
from
   a     
left join
   a_xref_b as xf1 
      on a.a_rid = xf1.a_rid      
inner join
   b as b_1 
      on xf1.b_rid = b_1.b_rid 
      and xf1.xref_type = 1     
left join
   a_xref_b xf2 
      on a.a_rid = xf2.a_rid      
inner join
   b as b_2 
      on xf2.b_rid = b_2.b_rid 
      and xf2.xref_type = 2
```

However it drops Sue's record.  If I change it to left joins from the xref to b, then I get duplicate records.

The real world scenario is a contact table cross referenced with an address table and the xref table has the type field.  We're trying to build a view to load the page.

Comment: Your question is fine, but things like greetings, expressing gratitude etc. are considered noise. You can just focus on your actual question and everything is fine. To improve the readybility of your sql you can use tools like http://www.freeformatter.com/sql-formatter.html to add proper indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you should add xref_type condition with a_xref_b table join.

```
select
   a.a1,
   b_1.b_rid,
   b_1.b1,
   b_1.b2,
   b_2.b_rid,
   b_2.b1,
   b_2.b2      
from
   a     
left join a_xref_b as xf1 on a.a_rid = xf1.a_rid      
   and xf1.xref_type = 1     
left join b as b_1 on xf1.b_rid = b_1.b_rid       
left join a_xref_b xf2 on a.a_rid = xf2.a_rid      
   and xf2.xref_type = 2
left join b as b_2 on xf2.b_rid = b_2.b_rid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Pivot table or use a SQL statement that give the same kind of result. For example:

```
;WITH    Main
          AS ( SELECT   a1 AS Name
                       ,b1 AS City
                       ,b2 AS Code
                       ,xref_type
               FROM     a_xref_b
                        LEFT JOIN a ON a_xref_b.a_rid = a.a_rid
                        LEFT JOIN b ON a_xref_b.b_rid = b.b_rid
             )
    SELECT  Name
           ,MAX(CASE WHEN xref_type = 1 THEN City
                END) FirstCity
           ,MAX(CASE WHEN xref_type = 1 THEN Code
                END) FirstCode
           ,MAX(CASE WHEN xref_type = 2 THEN City
                END) AlternateCity
           ,MAX(CASE WHEN xref_type = 2 THEN Code
                END) AlternateCode
    FROM    Main
    GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be using Union:

```
select max(name) name, max(id1) id1, max(city1) city1, max(state1) state1, max(id2) id2, max(city2) city2, max(state2) state2
from(
    select a.a1 as name, xf1.b_rid id1, xf1.b1 city1, xf1.b2 state1, null id2, null city2, null state2
    from a left join 
    (select a_rid, b1, b2, b.b_rid from a_xref_b inner join b on a_xref_b.b_rid = b.b_rid 
    where xref_type = 1) xf1 on a.a_rid = xf1.a_rid 
    union
    select a.a1 as name, null id1, null city1, null state1,xf1.b_rid id2, xf1.b1 city2, xf1.b2 state2
    from a left join 
    (select a_rid, b1, b2, b.b_rid from a_xref_b inner join b on a_xref_b.b_rid = b.b_rid 
    where xref_type = 2) xf1 on a.a_rid = xf1.a_rid 
)t group by name
```